# Simple stitching code

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++, graphics, mfc

It is first time when I am using OpenCV, and that is for made a simple image stitching ... and I was tried the following simple code:

```
    Mat resImage;
    Mat image1 = imread(_T("D:\\Tempx\\Image1.bmp"), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    Mat image2 = imread(_T("D:\\Tempx\\Image2.bmp"), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    std::vector<cv::Mat> vImg;

    vImg.push_back(image1);
    vImg.push_back(image2);

    Stitcher stitcher = Stitcher::createDefault(TRUE);
    Stitcher::Status stat = stitcher.stitch(vImg, resImage); // <-- crash the program !!!
    if(cv::Stitcher::OK != stat)
        sError.Format(_T("Error while stitching the images."));

    std::vector<int> compression_params;
    compression_params.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION);
    compression_params.push_back(9);

    imwrite(_T("D:\\Tempx\\Image3.bmp"), resImage, compression_params);
```

but on line:

```
stitcher.stitch(vImg, resImage);
```

the program has crashed:

[image]

might be something simple, might be not ... could you take a look and tell me a hint/idea, anything ? Thank you.

Comment: As per the documentation  createDefault(bool try_use_gpu = false); I would suggest you to use False instead of true as parameter. (I am not sure though)

Comment: I already tried that, exactly the same behavior. :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing something is wrong with your images. Make sure they are read correctly, e.g., by imwrite into new files. Also test with another pair of images first. If all those pass, then probably it fails to estimate the camera parameters for some reason.

**Update:**
It seems the feature extractor has an issue, difficult to tell what's gone wrong with just the trace back you've posted. Set the feature extractor in the code and see how it goes:

```
Stitcher stitch = Stitcher::createDefault(FALSE);
stitch.setFeaturesFinder(new detail::OrbFeaturesFinder());
```

The first line is the same as in your code, in the second line we just tell the stitcher what feature extractor to use.

Comment: I checked that, the loaded images I saved on HDD, and they are stored correctly, so, the problem it is not there ...

Comment: Then I suggest you share your images, someone can try to run the same code on your images and then can see what's wrong...

Comment: Sure, this a good idea ! But for that, I should create another response, I hope that admins of this forum would understand.

Answer (score 0):

Images for stitching:
[image]

and

[image]

and the code is:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/stitching.hpp>

    Mat image1 = imread(_T("D:/Tempx/Image1.bmp"), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYCOLOR);
    Mat image2 = imread(_T("D:/Tempx/Image2.bmp"), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYCOLOR);

    vImg.push_back(image1);
    vImg.push_back(image2);

    Mat resImage;
    Stitcher stitch = Stitcher::createDefault(FALSE);
    Stitcher::Status stat = stitch.stitch(vImg, resImage);
    if(Stitcher::OK != stat)
        MessageBox(_T("Error while stitching the images."));

    std::vector<int> compression_params;
    compression_params.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION);
    compression_params.push_back(9);

    imwrite(_T("D:/Tempx/Image3.bmp"), resImage, compression_params);
```